# Proper exception handling on Task.Wait() where initial task must complete first

Tags: exception, async-await

I'm not quite understanding the exception handling in await-able tasks.  I have a primary task that needs to complete and yield its result to dependent tasks.  So, the primary task must complete first, then, the subsequent tasks can run asynchronously.  If the initial/primary task fails and throws an exception, I need to handle the exception properly and exit the program.  If the 2 dependent tasks hit any exceptions, I just need to report them properly.  Two things are happening in the code below... 1) Task 2 and 3 are running synchronously (I want them to run asynchronously)... AND 2) if I uncomment the exception throw inside DoStringStuff, I will get the "Exception User-Unhandled" message and the program stops (and I want this exception to bubble up to the top like normal and simply be printed to the console). I'm missing some important semantics here. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated!

UPDATE:

I found the issue, if this will help anyone... I needed to declare all my tasks at the outset of the function (not dynamically).  Below is the working code.  The Exceptions (if any) will propagate up as expected.

```
await parent();

Console.ReadKey();

static async Task parent()
{
    Console.WriteLine("start of parent");

    string sResult;

    try
    {
        sResult = MyTask1("1111");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        string result = await DoRemainingTasks(sResult);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("end of parent");
}

static async Task<string> DoRemainingTasks(string sResult)
{
    Task<string> task2 = MyTask2(sResult);
    Task<string> task3 = MyTask3("3333");

    string t2Result = string.Empty;
    string t3Result = string.Empty;


    try
    {
        t2Result = await task2;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 issue. Error = " + ex.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        t3Result = await task3;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task 3 issue. Error = " + ex.Message);
    }

    return "Remaining tasks done: " + t2Result + "... " + t3Result;
}

static Task<string> DoStringStuff(string s)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        Console.Write(c);

        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    return Task.FromResult(s);
}

static async Task<string> DoStringStuffAsync(string s)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            Console.Write(c);

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        return s;
    });
    //throw new Exception($"task {s} failure");
}

static string MyTask1(string svar)
{
    try
    {
        DoStringStuff(svar);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("task 1 done");

    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    return "2222";
}


static async Task<string> MyTask2(string svar)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        string s = await DoStringStuffAsync(svar);

        return "task done for " + s;
    });
}


static async Task<string> MyTask3(string svar)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        string s = await DoStringStuffAsync(svar);

        return "task done for " + s;
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code has task running sequentially.

Comment: Hello Paulo. I expect Task1 to run first, and it does.  But, by await-ing Task2 and Task3 after Task1 completes, I was hoping they would run async.  Maybe I didn't connect all the dots here somehow?

Comment: `Exception User-Unhandled` - this is normal when running in the debugger. Continue the program and you should see it caught properly.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  Just read that a few min ago on the MS site:"When "Just My Code" is enabled, Visual Studio in some cases will break on the line that throws the exception and display an error message that says "exception not handled by user code." This error is benign. You can press F5 to continue and see the exception-handling behavior that is demonstrated in these examples. To prevent Visual Studio from breaking on the first error, just uncheck the Enable Just My Code checkbox under Tools, Options, Debugging, General."